# What make model and year is this vintage Trek?

Tags: trek

[image: Vintage rek Road Bike]

Serial number x 417024 . I'm trying to identify what year, make and model this Trek. Owner says it's an Emonda ALR 1997. However from what I can see Emondas weren't made till 2015. I think it's an early 90s T200. Some of the components have been changed but it has Shimano 105 rear derailleur and brake set. Sugino crank. The fork is chrome. Any ideas? Gregory

Comment: bikepedia.com database would be a good start - From memory the T200's were tandems.

Comment: I would guess early 80s, but I can't make out the brakes, and they are probably the most distinguishing characteristic.

Comment: It is definitely a Frankenstrek

Comment: I'd also go with early 80s, but I'm not entirely sure it even is a trek.

Answer (score 2):

According to  [Vintage Trek](http://www.vintage-trek.com/SerialNumbers.htm), six digit serial numbers starting with 36xxxx to 44xxxx (this is an estimate based on Trek owners' submissions to this website) were stamped on Trek bikes for the MODEL year 1989.

Perusing Trek's 1989 catalog, the closest matches are the 1500, which is an aluminum frame.  If your frame is steel, it's likeliest the 400 or 330.  Someone mentioned "Frankentrek" in the comments and it's pretty apt in this case.  I suspect your frame is steel, which puts it in the road 420 or 330 level. The 105 componentry is used in the 1400 & 1500 models. That fork is used in yet a third model, and your rear triangle looks more like Trek's mountain bike offerings of 1989, specifically the 820 antelope.  I'm specifically talking about the upper aspect of the seat stays, where it appears the "investment cast seat lug" is absent.  The mountain 820 has stays that more closely match your picture.

Comment: HA! Frankentrek..lol. thanks everyone I passed on it. I bought a different one and want to know the make and model. I'll post later. Thx everyone for your help. I had a feeling especially when they said it was an Edmondo. I would have bought if the frame alone of it were.

Comment: @GregoryRoper Please post pictures better than this one. Pictures with any decals / logos, components, frame characteristics (rear drop out, lug work if applicable etc.) clearly visible. Thanks!